# Save queue data in Python

Tags: python, database, queue

I have written a Python class, Queue. This class basically adds, removes and re-arranges the data in the queue.

How to save the data of the Queue? Whenever I re-run my code, all the data inside the queue is lost.

How to save the data so that, I can use the previous saved data?

This is the small code for the same ....

```
class Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = list()

    def add(self, item):
        if item not in self.queue:
            self.queue.insert(0, item)
            return True
        return False

    def remove(self):
        print("Element Popped")
        return self.queue.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.queue)

    def search_queue(self, item):
        with queue.mutex:
            if item in self.queue:
                flag = 1
            else:
                flag = 0
            return flag

    def arrange_queue(self, item):
        ..............
        ..........
        .....
```

Comment: How about storing data in file or database?

Comment: Well, technically you can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module to store your Queue object in a binary format to a filesystem and load it afterwards. But I also suggest to use file or database to store your information.

Comment: @Mayur I thought of storing it in the database ... but .. will it follow the FIFO approach ?

Comment: You might look at Redis, which can persist various datatypes that are relevant to this.

Answer (score 2):

## Python object serialization & persistence

You could use the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html) module to store and load data to and from disk.

- To **store** data to a file you can use [`pickle.dump(obj, file)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump)
- To **load** data from a given file use [`pickle.load(file)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html#pickle.load)

#### Example

```
import pickle

class Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = list()

    def add(self, item):
        if item not in self.queue:
            self.queue.insert(0, item)
            return True
        return False


# edit your queue & add elements as you wish
my_queue = Queue()
my_queue.add(1) 
my_queue.add(2) 

# save
with open("my_saved_queue.obj","wb+") as queue_save_file:
    pickle.dump(my_queue, queue_save_file)

print(f"> saved queue: {my_queue.queue}")    

# load
with open("my_saved_queue.obj","rb") as queue_save_file:
    my_loaded_queue: Queue = pickle.load(queue_save_file)

print(f"> loaded queue: {my_loaded_queue.queue}")

# output:
# > saved queue: [2, 1]
# > loaded queue: [2, 1]
```

#### Additional information

More information can be found in the official Python documentation in the chapter [Persistence](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/persistence.html).

Comment: For Python 3. my_queue.add(...) will throw an error. Use my_queue.put(...) instead.

Comment: Also, your code to save "my_queue" returns the error: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

Comment: @Nuelsian Please be aware that I didn't use Python's build-in class `Queue` - I used the class which was defined in the question of the OP. I updated my answer to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

you must save it to file and then read from that file every time you run your program

`def save(list)
    file=open('filename',r+)
    for item in list:
        file.write(item)
        file.write('\n')
    file.close()`

the r+ is the mode which you opened the file in and it means read and write together so later you can read from the file as follows

`for line in file.readlines():
    print line`

it will read each line in the file separately